# Why does a simple operation takes so much memory on TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a GeForce GTX 750 Ti,with 2GB memory. I am studying these tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics

```
import numpy as np

ndarray = np.ones([3, 3])

print("TensorFlow operations convert numpy arrays to Tensors automatically")
tensor = tf.multiply(ndarray, 42)
```

The multiply() operation throws a out of memory error message. That should needs a little memory. Right?

Tensorflow 2 on my iPython terminal message:

```
2019-12-11 13:53:43.455004: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 122 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2019-12-11 13:53:43.457654: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:830] failed to allocate 122.81M (128778240 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2019-12-11 13:53:43.862834: F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:175] Check failed: err == cudaSuccess || err == cudaErrorInvalidValue Unexpected CUDA error: out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Are you sure that any other process is not hogging the GPU?

Comment: Yes. A python process under anaconda is using most of the GPU shown by nvidia-smi. I killed it and it works. Very strange how the python is using it. It does nothing.